# Issue with AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm using `AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap()` to create an object in a different `AppDomain`. I couldn't get it to work because it kept throwing the following error at me:

> Could not load file or assembly 'COMon, Version=2.0.4960.27874, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

However, I found that it is because it tries to load my DLL (which has the same name as my .NET assembly).

This is how I call the method:

```
_script = (Script)_appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "COMon.Scripting.Script");
```

It works fine as long as there isn't a native DLL file with the same name as my .NET assembly. Why does this happen when I'm passing it the full path and filename of my .NET assembly?

Comment: Can you word that in an entirely different way? Are you saying there is another DLL with the same name as your managed DLL? Why not just change the name of the managed DLL?

Comment: My .NET application is named COMon.exe, I also have a native DLL that's named COMon.dll. I could just rename the DLL, I just find it strange that it tries to look in the DLL when I passed the full path of my executable

Comment: Gotcha - that is strange; Have you tried turning on Fusion logging to see what the heck the runtime is trying to do during assembly load?

Comment: I've hadn't heard of Fusion logs until now, I'll look into that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I'm passing it the full path and filename of my .NET assembly?

That's not how the method works.  The first argument is the *display name* of the assembly.  It is not a file name.  The MSDN article recommends that you take a look at Assembly.FullName to learn more about display names.

So the normal CLR search rules will be in effect for finding the assembly.  It will look in the GAC first, then in the probing path for the AppDomain.  With a quirk that you didn't count on, the CLR does **not** pay attention to the filename extension for a file.  The display name for an assembly doesn't specify it.   So it considers an EXE and a DLL equivalent.  Something you can see back in the trace for Fuslogvw.exe, the utility you always want to use when you have trouble like this.  And in other places, adding a reference to an EXE works fine for example.

So it finds COMon.exe and that's a kaboom, it is not a managed assembly.

It isn't that clear what the proper workaround might be in your case, other than simply renaming the assembly.  When you tinker with AppDomains then you typically also want to use AppDomainSetup and set the ApplicationBase or PrivateBinPath property.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Don't you mean the second argument though?    ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h7t2a2.aspx ). I'm now calling it like so: _script = (Script)_appDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, typeof(COMon.Scripting.Script).FullName);

Comment: No, I meant the first.  Assembly.Location is a file path, not an assembly display name.

Comment: @HansPassant Thought that might be the case...well answered